# Increase the Height of Column Header in a Windows Forms DataGrid (Not DataGridView)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, .net-1.1

I am working on a Windows Forms application and I have a `DataGrid` for which I am trying to increase the height of the column headers.

I know how its done for a datagridview but I am unsure about the `DataGrid`.

I have a column named `Actual \n Qty`, and this is being displayed as below:

[image]

May I know a way we could increase column header height?

Comment: It is CaptionFont.Size

Comment: @HansPassant I think this just increases the size of text in the header but not the height of the header row? I have a column name in multiple lines but two lines doesn't fit in the current header row

Comment: @Dev Is it really `.Net 1.1` or you just tagged with it because of `DataGrid`? If it's just because of `DataGrid`, you can change the tag to `.Net`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Height of the column header in [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) is calculated based on [`HeaderFont`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid.headerfont?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property and is stored in a private filed [`headerFontHeight`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGrid.cs,92bef2ee694df74c). You can get the field using reflection and change its value this way:

```
var p = typeof(DataGrid).GetField("headerFontHeight",
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
p.SetValue(dataGrid1, dataGrid1.HeaderFont.Height * 2);

var m = typeof(DataGrid).GetMethod("OnLayout",
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
m.Invoke(dataGrid1, new object[] { null });
dataGrid1.Invalidate();
```

[image]

You can assign the height which you think is enough or you can calculate the height of text of all columns and set the field to the maximum value.

Comment: You must be the only one who know about this code! It is not intuitive at all! Congratulations on figuring it out.

Comment: @NoChance  I didn't find a better solution by searching in [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGrid.cs,5383) of [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Comment: I thought I'd try "some\ntext" but for some reason it did not work in my case - Maybe your way is the only way! Stay safe.